# To what extent does imputed data on item level have to respect the range of plausible values when one is interested in the aggregated scores? (MICE)

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I’m aiming to impute data on Likert-Scale item level for a nested dataset using the MICE package.
The data is nested in the sense that participants (>2000) belong to different clusters (around 100 of them). Due to the length of the original questionnaire, a design choice was made to only display a maximum number of the scales to each respondent, thus creating missingness by design. Which scales were displayed was decided by a random number generator so we can consider the missingness for those items/scales M(C)AR. Missingness is mostly restricted to participant level only.

I would like to impute the missing data on item level while also taking into account the multilevel structure.
In the end, the mean score per respondent for each scale and their related statistics (e.g. overall correlations between constructs, intra-class correlations, etc.) are the values of interest. The mean scores per scale will be calculated via passive imputation after the item scores have been imputed.

**Now my question:**
To what extent does the imputed data on item level have to respect the range of plausible values (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, strictly)? Would “impossible” values (e.g. 0.58, 1.5, etc.) also be acceptable, as long as the values of interest (mean scores per scale) are reasonable?

E.g. [Nguyen, Carlin, Lee (2017)](https://ete-online.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12982-017-0062-6) state *“However, it is also important to keep in mind that the goal of MI is not to recover or replace the missing values, rather it is to produce valid analytic results in the presence of missing data. Simulation studies have indicated that it is not essential that imputed values fall within plausible or possible ranges [28, 31].”* (p. 4).

**A bit more background information:**

To take into account the categorical nature of the Likter-Scale items, I've initially looked at two-level predictive mean matching (method 2l.pmm). Because this method only imputations within the observed data range all items received plausible value.
Inspection of the density plots showed a close match between the imputed and observed values for basically all items. Therefore, also the calculated mean scores based on the imputed data are very comparable to the observed mean scores. Yet, overall correlations between the scale means and also the intra-class correlations were too low when compared to their counterparts that were based on only the observed data. Especially, when considering that the missingness is mainly random by design, I would expect no meaningful differences between the observed and the imputed groups.

Surprisingly, single-level methods pmm and polr (for ordered data) performed clearly better and preserved the overall correlations, but as expected also suffered from lower intra-class correlations due to not taking the cluster structure into account.

However, 2l.pan which imputes data using continuous values rather than categorical values preserved the original correlations of the mean scores and also the intra-class correlations of the observed data very well. Also, the distribution of the mean scores was preserved, so looking only at the aggregated values the imputation results seem valid and plausible. However, on individual item level 2l.pan of course produced "impossible" results e.g. continuous values between are above the range of possible answer options.

Thus, my earlier question if this makes any sense, also given what Nguyen, Carlin, Lee (2017) state in their paper.

Comment: What is the eventual model you want to run? If a multilevel (mixed) model, will you have random slopes?

Comment: No, the final model will contain the random intercept, but no random slopes.

Comment: Thanks - I was asking because I was thinking that you could use something like `jomo` to impute based on the ultimate model you want to run. https://www.ucl.ac.uk/population-health-sciences/sites/population_health_sciences/files/quartagno_1.pdf Also, I am curious why you want to impute all this data if it is MCAR? Under that missing mechanism OLS and other similar techniques are valid approaches for recovering parameter estimates.